# how to show alert on row click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

can you please tell me how to get alert on row click .I want to show Id on row click.and What to show different alert on delete button (using e.stopPropogation()) take care care of bubbling effect.can we remove row list using click of delete button?

http://jsfiddle.net/vxw58/6/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#add').click(function() {
     var listItems = $("#list").children();
     var count = listItems.length;
     var id = "tc_" + parseInt(count + 1);
     alert(parseInt(count + 1))
     $('#list').append(' <li id=' + id + '><a href="acura.html" class="rowclick">' + id + '</a></li>');
     $('#list').listview('refresh');
    })
})

$(document).on('click', '.rowclick', function() {
    alert(this.id)
})
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vxw58/7/, Anchor with class `.rowclick` has text not ID. So use `alert($(this).text())`

Comment: you need to use _split icon_ if you want to handle different events for the same `li`.

Comment: @Satpal I need ID not text

Comment: click is handled by `a` tag not `li`, so you need `$(this).closest("li")[0].id` on `.rowclick`. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/vxw58/12/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vxw58/13/ please check it is showing error..how to remove the row

Comment: how to remove on delete button ?

Comment: @omar can you please tell me I will remove row  ?

Comment: you want to remove delete button on click?

Comment: no .I want to remove row on delete button (X button),

Comment: Please I need be careful about bubbling effect

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51427/discussion-between-user3530755-and-omar)

Comment: use split button http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/vxw58/16/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *Split Button* feature to handle different functions on the same `li`.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="delete">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="row">Item</a>
    <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Give each button a different `class` to handle separate jobs.

```
$(document).on("click", ".row", function () {
  /* do something */
}).on("click", ".delete", function () {
  $(this).closest("li").remove();
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/vxw58/18/)**

Comment: But there is problem in that these are the step 1) I create three row (after) pressing the three time add button.Then press (X) button on second row

Comment: then press add button it generate duplicate row having same id(

Comment: @user3530755 pls explain what's exactly happening.

Comment: can you look this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294919/how-to-make-nested-list-in-slide-panel-in-jquerry?noredirect=1#comment35659085_23294919

Comment: @user3530755 fixed http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/TDy9y/ its counter issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem makes different sense here. After doing "inspect element", i found in your code row `tc_1` overlap delete button (i.e z-index).

So, as soon as you click on delete button the click event of delete not fired accually.

Try to set some CSS property with your Row and delete button -

```
.rowclick
{
 z-index:0;  
}

.ui-icon-delete
{
 z-index:1;  
}
```

[Working Example with different- 2 alert](http://jsfiddle.net/vxw58/15/)

[Demo : Delete Row](http://jsfiddle.net/vxw58/17/)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<button id="add">ADD</button>
<ul data-role="listview" data-icon="delete" 
data-theme="b" id="list" class="hello">


</ul>
```

> $(document).ready(function(){

```
$('#add').click(function(){
   var listItems = $("#list").children();

     var count = listItems.length;
    var id="tc_"+parseInt(count+1);
    alert(parseInt(count+1))
$('#list').append(' <li id='+id+' class="hello"><a href="acura.html"      class="rowclick">'+id+'</a></li>');
    $('#list').listview('refresh');
})
```

})

$(document).on('click','.hello',function(){
  alert(this.id)

})