# how to make nested list in slide panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

Can you please tell me how to make a nested list in slide panel in jQuery?
I am able to make a slide panel, but I want to make nested list in left panel in jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/qUMbC/31/

can we make nested list in slide panel ?

```
<div data-role="page" class="jqm-demos" data-quicklinks="true">
    <div data-role="header">
            <h1>External panels</h1>

    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content jqm-fullwidth">  <a href="#externalpanel" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-mini">Open External Panel</a>

    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="panel" id="externalpanel" data-position="left" data-display="reveal" data-theme="a">
     <h2>Menu</h2>

    <ul data-role="listview" style="padding-right: 8px">
        <li data-icon="false"><a href="#" class='sub1'>Submenu 1</a>

        </li>
        <li data-icon="false"><a href="#" class="sub2">Submenu 2</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- submenu -->

    </div>
```

Comment: You want the nested elements to display when you click on one of the menu items?

Comment: Actually I need When User click button('open external panel').it display nested list as show in image

Comment: I mean I need static nested list when user click button in left panel

Comment: I need nested list instead of "submenu 1 and submenu2 " buttons

Comment: To get expandable, hierarchical lists of arbitrary depth you could go with a treeview/treegrid (http://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/tree+view/) but the usability on small mobile devices might not be that good. Perhaps a drill-down menu with breadcrumbs would be better, e.g. http://filamentgroup.com/examples/menus/ipod.php

Comment: You mean something like that http://jsfiddle.net/qUMbC/42/?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the inner list to remain hidden until its parent is clicked, something like this might give you an idea:

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="myList" data-role="listview" style="padding-right: 8px">
    <li data-icon="false"><a href="#" class='sub1'>Submenu1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-icon="false"><a href="#" class="sub2">Submenu 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
#myList ul {
    display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#myList > li').click(function() {
    var subList = $(this).children('ul');
    if (subList.is(":hidden"))
        subList.slideDown(200);
    else
        subList.slideUp(200);
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qUMbC/43/)